# How to get time from timestamp/ DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have a `DateTime` property, how can i get only the `Timepart`?

eg-

[Code]

```
DateTime DepartureTime {get; set;}
```

If time is `04/02/2014 5:30:00 PM`, I only want the time(`5:30 PM`) part in `DateTime`. I don't want it in `String` as the return type I want is `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

The property `TimeOfDay` of a `DateTime`, like

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

will return the time part of the DateTime. You must be aware that this property returns a `TimeSpan` struct and not a `DateTime`. The returned value will count the time of the day since midnight of the same day.

If you want to transform the `TimeSpan` back into a `DateTime`, there is a constructor that you can use:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var timeAsDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, date.TimeOfDay.Hours, date.TimeOfDay.Minutes, date.TimeOfDay.Seconds);
```

Comment: +1. 31 second too slow :) MSDN link - [TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @aw04 - Converting `TimeSpan` to `DateTime` relative to any day OP wants is relatively simple (Note that OP did not specify what resulting DateTime object should look like)... I could be wrong but adding something to something with `+` should not be very hard...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah this is a good answer, I think maybe I misread the question at first although it's hard to tell exactly what it is needed for.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the time portion as a string without losing the data type of `DateTime` by calling `ToShortTimeString()` when you want to display it.

It depends on what you want to do with the time. If you need to do more than display it, the first answer is probably more relevant but there are options depending on your needs.

Comment: i want to sort the time in ascending/ descending. so i want only the time part in AM/PM format like 5:30 PM

 .TimeOfDay will give time in 24 hour format, right? is there a way to convert it to 12 hour format?

  And can we convert Timespan to DateTime ?

Comment: @user3478233 Pierre gives an example of this